# Run a launch file in ubuntu from an android device

Tags: rosbridge, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

What I want to do is to run a launch file, which is ready on an ubuntu laptop and will run some nodes created by roscpp, from an android device where the user just needs to operate from some buttons in a web browser, if possible.

In the beginning I thought rosbridge_suite would be perfect for me. However, when I explore rosbridge_suite tutorials, I found what the client does in the browser on the android side is similar to the work of a node (i.e., publishing/subscribing topics or calling a service).  If I just want to run the nodes created in the ubuntu, rosbridge_suite doesn't seem to serve my purpose (please correct me if I am wrong), or maybe is there a way to send ubuntu shell instructions (i.e., roslaunch) from an android browser?

It seems that most people are using rosjava as long as it refers to the android platform. Would rosjava be a solution to my question (maybe not through a browser), or is there even a simple better way to do that? Thanks for anyone's help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/92691/run-a-launch-file-in-ubuntu-from-an-android-device/) by [kevinma](https://answers.ros.org/users/5755/kevinma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I believe you would benefit from looking at this page http://answers.ros.org/question/59742/rosjava-launch-another-node-from-within-rosjava-node/

---

Originally posted by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) with karma: 796 on 2013-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0